# The statement in the for loop did not run

Tags: python

The statement I added **** at the end did not run, can anyone tell me why it happens.
Btw, I even put a test statement right below that statement, and the test statement did ran.

```
size = int(input())
numList = []
for i in range(size):
    num = int(input())
    numList.append(num)

numList.sort()
count = 0
newList = []
useless = 0
print(numList)
for j in range(size):
    if(j+1==size):
        newList.append(numList[j]) ***************
        print(numList[j])
        break
    if(numList[j+1]==numList[j]):
        useless=1
    else:
        newList.append(numList[j])
        count = count +1
        
for k in range(count):
    print(newList[k])
```

Comment: What is the example input and output?

Comment: What do you mean it didn't run, it ***did*** run, just that the result is not the same as your expected result doesn't mean it "didn't" run

Comment: You could use a debugger for these kind of problem. Just follow the execution flow.

Answer (score 0):

Do it like:

```
for k in newList:
     print(k)
```

If that not statment which you want, tell us which its and give us output